# Downloading from URL causes binary response

Tags: android

I try to get string from this url:
http://autoc.finance.yahoo.com/autoc?query=google&callback=YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback

When I look at this in Chrome, I see correct JavaScript responce but when download it from the app with the same headers, I get binary response. How can I get the same correct response in the app?

**EDIT:**
Code:

```
public RESTResponse<T> get(String url) {
    HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
    setHeaders(get);
    return execute(get);
}                                                         

private void setHeaders(HttpRequestBase request) {
    request.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml");
    request.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch");
    request.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
}

private RESTResponse<T> execute(HttpRequestBase request) {
    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        return responseFactory.create(response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't perform request.", e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hard to tell what's the problem without seeing your code - but you could use that one:

https://github.com/ligi/LigiAndroidCommons/blob/master/src/org/ligi/android/common/net/NetHelper.java

Comment: hm I do not see a problem in the code you posted - can you post the full code?